# Find Alt-code for any character

Tags: windows-7, unicode, character-encoding

Sometimes, an alt-code that I find on the internet does not work on my PC, for example Pi alt code (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>227</kbd>) throws Ń isntead of π.
So I need to use the character in clipboard (or in a file or wherever) and conver it to Alt-code compatible with my system. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

The Alt code are system-dependent: they depend on the local of the system. In some situations, it also depends on the application software. An <kbd>Alt</kbd> *number* code works consistently only when *number* is less than 127.

General info: [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm).

Answer (score 7):

You can start "Character map", choose your font, search you character and at the bottom (in the status bar) is the Alt code you need.

(In Windows 7 you can press `Start` and begin type `Character map` en choose it at the top.)

The fact that you get a different character with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>227</kbd> is probably that you're using a different font. So choosing the right font in "Character map" is important.

BTW nowadays the <kbd>Alt</kbd> combinations consists of a 4 digit number to accommodate a wider range of Unicode characters. The three numbers still work but the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>227</kbd> is different from <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0227</kbd>.

[image: Character map]

Comment: It's not because of different font. The difference is the same accross fonts and applications.

Comment: Also, the keystroke is NOT displayed for all the letters. [Have a look.](http://u8.8u.cz/images/screenshots/charmap.png)

Comment: Alt+227 is Pi in the old MS-DOS ascii-set. It used to work in MS-DOS applications (I think thats why they float all over the internet). I see you are right that some letters don't have Alt-codes. I should test if the Alt+`+` works with the Unicode ones.

Comment: I can't get the Pi to work either in random application. I can however get it to work in Wordpad and Word. Type `03c0`. Now type Alt+X and the `03c0` is converted to `π`. This is method 4 of the link Jukka suggested. I can't get the Alt+`+`+code to work.

Comment: You must change the registry entry and relogin. I didn't try it however, so maybe it doesn't work at all. (I have heavy problems with relogin or restart, because of my system status)
Besides that, I just discovered zergling walking on my wall, so I'm focusing on it.

Comment: You don't need to change the registry. Rik is correct that it can change from font to font, although many common fonts will use the same value for the same characters. You also need to set the character encoding. In Charmap, checkmark the box for "Advanced View" and you'll have a few more options. One is "character set", which is essentially Codepage. In Arial, pi is "0xE3" which is indeed 227. But the reason it may not work "on the internet" is that the HTML code for pi is &#928 or &Pi;  i.e. what you see on a webpage is not the ascii representation of pi. Also some programs don't accept alt+

Answer (score 3):

Alt codes only work up to 255. There's a slight trick: adding a lead 0 will give you *consistent*  results. Alt-0227 consistently is `ã`. But since Alt codes only work up to 0255, it's clear that the thousands of characters needed for Chinese, Korean, Russian, Greek, etc. can't all be supported. The only greek character I found was Alt-0181 µ (mu).

Comment: `Alt+0181` represents Micro Sign (`µ`, Unicode `U+00B5`) not Greek Small Letter Mu (`μ`, Unicode `U+03BC`). Similar or even seemingly same glyph (look) but different character! Anyone could get a proof using next windows command line statement: `if "µ"=="μ" (echo same) else (echo diff)`

Comment: @JosefZ: As an engineer, I consider `3 micrometer = 3 micron = 3 mu`. And Unicode apparently agrees with me, `U+00B5` is a [compatibility character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_compatibility_characters#Semantically_distinct_characters). They couldn't **move** `µ` to `U+03BC` without breaking the Latin-1 block. (U+0080-U+00FF is identical to 8859-1 0x80-oxFF) so they copied it.

Comment: From your source: _Though not the intention of Unicode to encode such measuring units the repertoire includes six (6) such symbols that **should not be used** by authors: the characters' decompositions should be used instead. …, Micro Sign (µ `U+00B5`: use `U+03BC` instead)_.

Comment: As a programmer: `if ("µ" -Match "μ") {"same"} else {"diff"}` in PowerShell (which supports Unicode natively) returns `diff`.

Comment: @JosefZ: Don't read too much in that. Microsoft is know to implement Unicode string comparison incorrectly, with ä being unequal to ä depending on the representation. It shouldn't have been a binary comparison.

Comment: From a programming perspective this isn't true at all. "Equality" can mean many different things to a program. Occasionally binary equality is exactly what you're after. Even with filesystems things are tricky. Beyond other vexxing issues, such as allowing newlines and EOF characters in filenames, filesystems may not normalize filenames, and when they do, there is still the issue that there are multiple approaches to normalization. What happens when different parts of the computer disagree on how things should be normalized? This isn't a Microsoft thing. Computers can be complicated.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, one way to enter codes is by referring to code page
437:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

For anything on that list, you just enter Alt followed by the
decimal code. For example for this character:

```
☺ U+263A
```

According to the chart is decimal `1`. So you will just enter
`Alt + 1`. Another method is Code Page 1252:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

For anything on that this, you just enter Alt followed by `0` and
the decimal code. For example for this character:

```
€ U+20AC
```

According to the chart is decmail `128`. So you will just enter
`Alt + 0128`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however I noticed that both of these tables have only a very limited number of characters - a lot less than is shown in charmap. And they also don't easily show you the actual ALT code. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I was same the problem but here...This solved my problem with ASCII code.

1. Open Control Panel > Region and Language
2. Go to 'Administrative' tab
3. On section 'Language for non-Unicode programs', click the button 'Change system locale...'
4. Select the language of your country, same language to your keyboard pre-configured in.